# How do I deep link to a specific Facebook post or page in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I'd like to use the iOS `fb://` deep linking scheme to point a user to a specific page or post within Facebook. `fb://` still works to open the Facebook iOS app, but none of the custom schemes work.

[I found this list of outdated custom schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook), and tried using `fb://post/<post_id>` specifically, but they all no longer work. Is it still possible to do this?

Comment: There is no supported way to deep link to Facebook

Comment: Thank you so much for this, @WizKid. I assume you wouldn't happen to know why, or when it could possibly be supported again, would you?

Comment: No idea. It never been supported

Comment: I see. Thanks again, @WizKid.

Comment: You can use `fb://page/{page_id}` to deep link to a specific page. Find your page ID using http://findmyfbid.com/

Comment: Actually, no that only works on Android :-(

Comment: But `fb://profile/{page_id}` **does** work on iOS 9 :-)